# Как отобразить фото в программе на c# wpf из базы данных?

Tags: c#, mysql, база-данных, wpf, sql-server

Как отобразить фото? Есть база mysql или mssql, и как лучше фото хранить в поле image или хранить ссылку на фото, которое хранится на сервере, если ссылку, то как тогда изменять/добавлять фото и загрузить его?

Answer (score 2):

Многое зависит от размера, количества и частоты обращения к фото. Хранить фото в реляционной базе данных можно, а можно хранить его в базе данных NoSQL, либо в файловой системе или на специальных сетях доставки контента, а в базе данных хранить пути к фото. Почему стоит хранить не в базе?

- Изображения могут обслуживаться как статика.
- Не требуется доступа к базе данных для извлечения изображения.
- Изображения могут кэшироваться.

Подключаются изображения в WPF с помощью компонента Image, например, для URL

```
<Image 
Source="{Binding Path=PhotoID, StringFormat='http://from.ru/Image.aspx?photoID={0}'}" />
```